# How to get Tridion FieldType in Tridion 2011?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to get the Field Type in Tridion 2011 TOM.NET?

The ItemField class has a name and definition, but I don't see the old trusted ItemType property.

I have a feeling I need to use the Definition property, but not sure what is the cleanest way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I use this mostly `itemField is EmbeddedSchemaField` and some times `itemField.GetType().Name`. I don't remember seeing ItemType even in 2009 (may be a custom utility?).

Comment: Field type isn't the same as item type, but as Ram pointed out it's all in the Type of the class anyway. So you can do an "is TypeX" check or GetType() as appropriate. You should put that in an answer, Ram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the following way to check the field type:

```cs
itemField is EmbeddedSchemaField

itemField is KeywordField
```

and Itemfield GetType also provides the same information as well.

```cs
switch (itemField.GetType().Name)
{
case "EmbeddedSchemaField":
   fieldType = "EmbeddedSchema";
   break;
case "DateField":
   fieldType = "Date Field";
   break;
case "MultiLineTextField":
   fieldType = "RTF Text";
   break;
default:
    break;
}
```